# how to search one value in (MYSQL and SQL Server) multiple columns without iteration/looping/cursor?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two databases. One database is in Mysql and other is in SQL Server.

The structure of both databases is same.

Now the issue is i want to search one value from multiple columns of a table.

what is the best approach and i don't want to use sub-queries in where clause.
I want to search from all columns but which 'll meet the condition.

I am trying with this (MySQL) query. Currently I am placing the hard-coded value than i 'll have to use the stored procedure.

Please correct. thank you

```
SELECT ID,
    NAME,
    IFNULL(ADDRESS1, '') ADDRESS1,
    IFNULL(PHONE_NO, '') PHONE_NO,
    IFNULL(Speciality, '') Speciality
FROM company  
WHERE 
    countryId  = 158 AND
    ('Makeup'='' OR NAME LIKE CONCAT('%','Makeup','%')) AND
    ('Makeup'='' OR ADDRESS1 LIKE CONCAT('%','Makeup','%')) AND
    ('Makeup'='' OR PHONE_NO LIKE CONCAT('%','Makeup','%')) AND
    CASE
        WHEN ''='' THEN 1=1
        ELSE (Speciality LIKE CONCAT('%','','%'))
    END
ORDER BY NAME ASC;
```

Comment: Gordon Linoff. thank you but my problem was not this. My query was not working even correct. I wanted to ask if it has some issue or not ?

Comment: Thank you all, I have found the issue. actually the data was missing or incorrect. My asked question has been answered but if you people help me to make the query best then it will be appreciated as per performance wise. Thank you –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to write code that works with multiple databases, I would suggest doing more work in the application layer.  Simply do:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, COALESCE(ADDRESS1, '') as ADDRESS1,
       COALESCE(PHONE_NO, '') as PHONE_NO,
       COALESCE(Speciality, '') as Speciality
FROM company  
WHERE countryId  = 158 AND
      NAME like '%Makeup%' AND
      ADDRESS1 like '%Makeup%' AND
      PHONE_NO like '%Makeup%' AND
      Specialty LIKE '%%'
ORDER BY NAME Asc;
```

Then, put the wildcards in the "Makeup" string in the application.  Two wildcards `%%` is the same as one `%`.  This will do exactly your logic . . . assuming the various columns are not null.

Also, use ANSI standard functions where possible.  `COALESCE()` is ANSI standard.  The above code should work across both databases.

Comment: Worth mentioning that having wildcards from both at the beginning and end end of the `LIKE` is going to hurt performance by a lot. In this case it will work, but generally that's not the best practice.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas . . . You should make the comment on the *question* not the *answer*.  This is what the OP has in the question.

Comment: @user6306245 . . . You should ask new questions (say about performance) as a *new* question, not in a comment.

Comment: Thank you all, I have found the issue. actually the data was missing or incorrect. My asked question has been answered but if you people help me to make the query best then it will be appreciated as per performance wise. Thank you –

Comment: Gordon i 'll mark this as answer but i also wrote about the best approach. Kindly allow to get another answer.